# Strange Behavior when printing "all powers of 2 that fit in a long"

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm attempting to print all powers of two from 2^0 onward that will fit into a long variable.

This is my code so far

```
    long y = 0;
    int iteration = 1;
    for (y = 1; y < 9223372036854775807L; y *= 2) {

        System.out.println("2 to the power of " + iteration + " is " +y);
        iteration++;
```

This behaves as expected until 2^63 when the console prints

```
2 to the power of 62 is 4611686018427387904
2 to the power of 63 is -9223372036854775808
2 to the power of 64 is 0
```

Then the program continually returns

```
2 to the power of 64 is 0
2 to the power of 65 is 0
2 to the power of 66 is 0
```

And so on.

What is happening here?

Comment: `y < 9223372036854775807L` amounts to “checking for overflow after it has already happened”

Comment: Alright, I'm fairly new to this, but I ended up changing it to
     for (y = 1; y < Long.MAX_VALUE && y > 0; y *= 2) { 
and that gives the desired result

Comment: You may remove " y < Long.MAX_VALUE &&" and the result will be the same. And you need to initialize iteration to 0 to get correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the final `y *= 2` is performed `y` becomes a value larger than that which can be stored as a long. As longs are two's complement in java, where the most significant bit indicates if a number is positive or negative, when you make a long larger than its max value the most significant bit changes from a 0 to a 1, meaning the value of the long becomes negative so your loop will never terminate. There is a good video on two's complement [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4) for a better explanation.